# Method overriding in Java Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

```
package P1;

public class Base {

   private void pri( ) { System.out.println("Base.pri()");  }

   void pac( ) {  System.out.println("Base.pac()");  }

   protected void pro( ) { System.out.println("Base.pro()"); }

   public void pub( ) { System.out.println("Base.pub()"); }

   public final void show( ) {
       pri();  
       pac();  
       pro();  
       pub(); 
   }    
}
```

and

```
package P2;

import P1.Base;

public class Concrete1 extends Base {
   public void pri( ) { System.out.println("Concrete1.pri()"); }
   public void pac( ) { System.out.println("Concrete1.pac()"); }
   public void pro( ) { System.out.println("Concrete1.pro()"); }
   public void pub( ) { System.out.println("Concrete1.pub()"); }
}
```

And I'm executing

```
Concrete1 c1 = new Concrete1();
c1.show( );
```

Now, the output is shown to be

> Base.pri()
>       Base.pac()
>       Concrete1.pro()
>       Concrete1.pub()

Can someone explain why this is so? From what I understood about inheritance, this ***should*** have happened:

1) P2.concrete1 inherits P1.Base
2) c1 object of concrete1 is created
3) `c1.show()` is called. Since P1.Base.show() is `public`, it can be called.
4) Now, in P2.concrete1 after inheritance, only it's own methods (pri, pac, pro, pub) and P1.Base's inheritable methods (pro, pub, show) are accessible.

Now WHY does it show Base.pri() and Base.pac() in the output when they're not even accessible?

It's clear that I've not got a very clear fundamental understanding of inheritance. Can someone explain this situation and how inheritance is actually 'structured'. I used to think that inheritable methods and fields of the superclass would just superimpose onto the subclass. But that line of reasoning is obviously wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: `Base.show` knows nothing about `Concrete1` and is not concerned with `Concrete1.pri` and `Concrete1.pac` as they override neither `Base.pri` nor `Base.pac`. You're wrong in saying they're not accessible because they are accessible to `Base.show`.

Comment: This answer explains it, because 'show' calls the method in the base class the Base methods would be used. The method is Base#show(); not Concrete#show(); However, Concrete#Pri(); would print 'Concrete1.pri() since that is the method available to it. Its actually pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is that you can only override methods that are visible. The first two methods, `pri` and `pac` are *private* and *package protected* respectively. Because nothing outside the class can see a *private* method, it can't be overridden. Similarly because `Concrete1` is in a different package from `Base` it can't see `Base.pac` so cannot override it.

What this means is that while you define a `pri` and `pac` method in `Concrete1`, they're just methods that happen to have the same name as the methods in `Base`, not overrides. The other two methods `pro` and `pub` are *protected* and *public* respectively, so are visible to `Concrete1`. As a result the `pro` and `pub` methods in `Concrete1` are overrides of the methods of the same name in `Base`.

Because `show` is defined in `Base`, it's compiled calling the 4 methods as defined in `Base`. When executed the JVM looks to see if any are overridden and if they are executes the overridden methods. As explained above, `pri` and `pac` are not overridden so the `Base` versions are executed where as `pro` and `pub` are so the `Concrete1` versions are executed.

If you were to move the `show` method into `Concrete1` instead of `Base` then it would execute the 4 methods as defined in `Concrete1` as those would be the methods visible to `show`.

Comment: Okay, so Java would first call Base.pub() from Base.show(), the it would check all the way down to the last subclass to see if something overrides it?

Comment: That is the way to think about it and the way it behaves. I suspect that the actual implementation is significantly more complicated than that. But if you think of the method dispatch behaving that way you will get the right result. That's the way I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Private and no-modifier methods are by design not visible to its subclass. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) for detailed explanation.